# Lock screen halts file copying in Nautilus

Tags: files, lock-screen, copy

Yesterday I left copying a large amount files about 220GB using nautilus, just copy/paste. I locked the screen with Crtl+Alt+L and this morning I expected it to have finished. However, to my horror, it was in the same position as yesterday. After locking and unlocking a few times I've verified that the copy operation stops when the screen is locked.

How can I avoid this? ie. that the copy operation continues while the screen is locked.  Ubuntu 16.04

For the moment I'm repeating the same copy using cp but I can't tell if this is being halted too while locking the screen because there isn't a progress indicator. How could I add a progress indicator to cp?

Answer (score 1):

For your second question - "How could I add a progress indicator to cp?" cp does't support displaying a progress indicator. For a command line copy command with a progress indicator, you can try rsync. Install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt install rsync
```

To use rsync with a progress indicator, run:

```
rsync -ah --progress <source> <destination>
```

More about copying files with a progress indicator [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-progress-during-file-transfer/).

Comment: I'm trying rsync and with --progress shows the copy percentage of the current copied file. As there are lots of small files I only see 100%, which is not too informative. Do you know if it's possible to show the copied percentage out of all the copied files?

Comment: With newer rsync versions, you can use "--info=progress2" instead of "--progress" for an overall copy progress indicator.

Comment: I get a global progress indicator, but the copy speed of rsync is really slow. It never goes over 120kB/s  and I'm in a wired network. I think nautilus copy was faster

Comment: too slow, I've calculated it's going to take 560h to copy everything!